# Unable to successfully run Parse Server locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to get a Parse server up and running locally. I'm following the readme that tells me to install parse-server and mongodb, then I run:

`parse-server --appId {app_id} --masterKey {key} --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test`

When I try to hit my Parse app locally, with the url `http://localhost:1337/parse`, calling the `foo` function, I get this response in my terminal

> error: Error handling request: ParseError { code: 141, message: 'Invalid function: "foo"' } code=141, message=Invalid function: "foo"
>   error: Invalid function: "foo" code=141, message=Invalid function: "foo"

`foo` is defined in `main.js` as:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('foo', function(request, resposne) {
    response.success("hi");
});
```

It's called from my objc code as

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"foo" withParameters:nil block:^(NSString *res, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog([error description]);
        } else {
            NSLog(res);
        }
    }];
```

**I'm also not able to call other functions in this code that I know work and are present. The issue seems to be not being able to locate the Parse server locally**

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here, would love some help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a cloud function directory. For example, `'./cloud/main.js'`

I'm not sure how to do that in command line, should be something like `--cloud ./cloud/main.js`

In your index.js file, it should look like this:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://....',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || '***',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '***',
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse'
});
```

And you can run `node index.js` to start server locally.